# Plot the sum of all but one variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have a dataframe with data on the number of TVs and radios owned by survey respondents in three different countries (Canada, Mexico, US) at two different points in time (now and before):

```
DF <- data.frame(TV_now = as.numeric(c(4, 9, 1, 0, 4, NA)),
                 TV_before = as.numeric(c(4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2)),
                 Radio_now = as.numeric(c(4, 5, 1, 5, 6, 9)),
                 Radio_before = as.numeric(c(6, 5, 3, 6, 7, 10)),
                 Country = as.factor(c("Mexico", "Canada", "US", "US", "Canada", "US")))
```

I want to sum the total value of each variable and then create a barplot that shows the number of TVs and radios owned by survey respondents now and before per country.

Now, if my dataframe didn't contain the `Country` factor, I could generate the plot in this way:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

DF %>% mutate_all(funs(sum), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  gather(key=Device, value=Number) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Device,fill=Device)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Device, y = Number), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

However, the variation

```
DF %>% mutate_all(funs(sum), na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  gather(key=Device, value=Number, -Country) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Device,fill=Device)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = Device, y = Number), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Country)
```

results in the error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors.
```

Is there a way to exclude the factor from `sum`, or another way to generate the intended plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the summarise function to sum up the different columns. Below I have summed up the numeric columns using dplyr's `summarise_if()` function.

```
DF <- data.frame(TV_now = as.numeric(c(4, 9, 1, 0, 4, NA)),
             TV_before = as.numeric(c(4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 2)),
             Radio_now = as.numeric(c(4, 5, 1, 5, 6, 9)),
             Radio_before = as.numeric(c(6, 5, 3, 6, 7, 10)),
             Country = as.factor(c("Mexico", "Canada", "US", "US", "Canada", "US")))

DF %>%
        group_by(Country) %>%
        summarise_if(is.numeric,sum,na.rm=TRUE) %>%
        gather(key=Device, value=Number, -Country) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=Device,fill=Device)) + 
        geom_bar(aes(x = Device, y = Number),position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
        facet_wrap(~Country)
```

The result is:

[image: Results plot]

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.